# Remove all zero decimal places except the decimal mark

Tags: python, format

I'd like to format a string that has only zeros after the decimal mark:
Example: `12.000` to `12.`

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to strip zeroes:

```
>>> '12.000'.rstrip('0')
'12.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format`:

```
>>> s = "12.000"
>>> "{0:.3}".format(s)
12.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use regex:

```
import re
s = '12.00'
re.sub(r'(.+)\.0+$',r'\1.',s)
>>> '12.'
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are looking for. If you need the "." after "12" ala "12.", use the other answers.

If you don't care about the dot, but just want to display the digits of your number, use this:

```
print('{0:1g}'.format(12.0000))
```

The "". will be there, it's still a float, you just can't see it with this method, which is different from the other ones. Also, this answer works in Python 3.x, not in Python 2.x.